# Spaces around code keywords

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27915508/874188) had no spaces around the keywords, and displayed as expected in my browser (Grazing, IOS 8; but Safari is similar).

[image: IOS8 screenshot]

I fixed it, but the author rolled back the edit, and left a comment that the text looked fine on Windows.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WE8ea.png) is his screenshot:

[image: Windows screen shots, two in parallel]

Regardless of looks, my gut reaction is that words should have spaces between them, whether they are code or plain text.  Markup rendering can change at any time, but the inherent linguistic semantics will not change so quickly.

For reference, here is a snippet of the answer with and without spaces.

> Which sets the value of`pieces`to`None`because the list`append()`method effectively returns that value.

Contrast with spaces:

> Which sets the value of `pieces` to `None` because the list `append()` method effectively returns that value.

I'm posting this here in the hope that the community can help resolve the matter.  Is there official guidance on this particular detail?  If not, is there a consensus one way or the other?

Comment: It seems highly reasonable always to separate words (by putting exacly *one* space - the other highly irritating issue is the usage of extra spaces) independently of the way they are intended to be formatted, be it plain text or code block. To my mind, this falls to the category of language purity. True, not everybody posting here have English language as their mother tongue, but all should do their best to write/correct questions/answers in a generally accepted manner. Despite emphasis is author-based, punctuation should not be dependent on author's view or rendering engine employed.

Comment: Beat me to the punch -- I was just about to click the Post button for my own meta question about this exact issue. FWIW the reference example you put at the end of your question isn't quite the same at the effect of doing it inline like `this` -- which brings up a another point, namely that in comments like here I can't remove leading and trailing spaces to compensate, an inconsistency that can be bit annoying...

Comment: @skuntsel Please feel free to post that as an answer, so that I can properly upvote you.  Thanks!

Comment: @martineau I'm sorry, I don't understand the difference between my example and your "inline like `this`" -- could you please elaborate?

Comment: @martineau: To "compensate" for _what_?

Comment: Also that firefox looks at least a few years old.

Comment: @tripleee: To compensate for the extra space that gets put in by my adding the \` characters around things, like `this` here.

Comment: @martineau: What "extra space"? That is not "extra space". If you don't like the formatting on Stack Overflow then feel free to write a custom stylesheet and run it within your browser, but writing strange formatting for _everyone_ is not an appropriate action. Markdown separates **form** from **function** and you are ruining the function because you have a minority qualm with the **form**.

Comment: Should this be a META.SE question? Just curious.

Comment: One more minor point: SE tweaks their styles on occasion. It's not inconceivable that the padding around inline code blocks could be reduced in the future, turning that semi-readable text into indecipherable garbage.

Comment: Indeed; if @martineau is unhappy with the "extra" space in the desktop style sheet, a bug report to fix that would be the reaction of choice. If and when it gets fixed, the texts which lack the "extra" spaces will need to be "vandalized" (if not sooner).

Comment: As a similar user of a heavily modded Firefox install on Windows... there is no excuse I can imagine for leaving out spaces around inline code. Install Scriptish or something already!

Comment: Here on IE11 and FireFox 34 on Windows and Safari on iPad, the two quoted blocks at the end of your post are almost indistinguishable. Kinda sounds like the lion's share of the blame lies with your obscure browser (especially since a user with 24.5k rep is saying nobody has ever complained before). Still, it makes absolutely no sense to not have spaces spaces between the words in the markdown.

Comment: @JLRishe: FWIW, I mentioned in one of my [earlier comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283362/spaces-around-code-keywords#comment141434_283362), that in the example at the end of triplee's post it is less noticeable than when done inline with \` delimiters which is where I commonly was doing it.

Comment: OK everyone, don't get your panties in a bunch, I'll stop doing it and perhaps also submit a trouble report. Overall that'll be fine because I didn't like having to do in the first place and was just trying to improve the visual quality of at least my own posts on SO. I feel that the comments suggesting that I was trolling or completely missing something that ought have been oh, so, obvious are wrong as well as unwarranted/unjustified.

Comment: @martineau If you do, please ping back here. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that we rule that in your particular situation the answer should be changed. What should we do regarding other questions? By curiosity, I checked @martineau profile (you are a senior user!) and his best answer also has this "feature": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4529901/931303. What we do about it? xD

Comment: @tripleee: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283459/355230

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I'm not sure and don't think it's really all that big of a deal. I've answered lots of questions here and have been doing it for some time, so going back and fixing them all would be a lot of work and not something I'm highly motivated to do (especially when I don't own them anymore as one commenter pointed-out, plus the way they are doesn't bother me nor the vast majority of other folks as far as I know).

Comment: @martineau, my point is: if we don't change the others, it is because changing them costs more than not changing them. If so, why did we changed this one in the first place?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: I find your use of the pronoun "we" in your comments both puzzling and amusing. It sounds like you think the folks who ask questions and post here on meta are royalty endowed with the power to make rulings or pronouncements for everyone else to obey. It also reminds me of the old joke where the Lone Ranger and his faithful sidekick, Tonto, are surrounded by hostile Indians, and the Lone Ranger asks Tonto, “What are we going to do?” who replies, “What do you mean ‘we,’ paleface?” (continued)

Comment: @J. C. Leitão: ... Well, as I've mentioned I think the whole matter's been blown out of proportion and am therefore very disinclined to go back though all my numerous answers and "unfix" any of them that don't fit what appears to be the current consensus about what I was doing. If they really bother you, be my guest (but please refrain from changing anything else).

Comment: (My "we" was referring to the 48-accepted question below that I downvoted). I was agreeing with you that this went out of proportions. My aim with the comment was to show that by changing the particular answer of this meta post, we are encouraging other users to change all your answers; and I don't believe that is a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: @J.C. Changing them doesn't "cost" anything.

Comment: SE style for inline code did not always include the extra spacing within the gray boxes.  If we'd kept it that way, I doubt anyone would ever be inclined to remove necessary spaces.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Yes, *of course* those code keywords should be surrounded by spaces.

It's entirely baffling to me that anyone could claim otherwise and not be trolling.

[image: Example of insane formatting]

Comment: Apparently you didn't look at how it's displayed in the screenshots on my desktop. Going in and editing my post again is basically vandalism as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @martineau: It looks absolutely fine in both screenshots. I will have to assume that it also looks absolutely fine with the correction in place (no, that is _not_ "vandalism"; don't be absurd) since you have _still_ not bothered to tell us your rationale for this bizarre formatting choice in the first place.

Comment: Works for me therefore it works for everybody!

Comment: It looks fine in my screenshots because they are both from when the answer has the extra spaces removed. I think it's ridiculous that folks on IOS think that everyone has to accommodate them because their software "thinks different". The fact that its hard to read in the editing section shown in your screenshot is just an unfortunate side-effect of my having to compensate for the extra space being introduced otherwise when the answer is view normally.

Comment: @martineau: When did I say I'm on iOS? I've never used iOS in my life. You seem to be coming at this backwards; _you_'re the one saying that everybody _else_ needs to accommodate _you_ and your highly unusual formatting, just because you perceive unacceptable spacing that literally nobody else has ever complained about. Your profile suggests that you are a grown man so I am left entirely baffled by this entire affair.

Comment: @martineau It's not just iOS (_Android too!_), but really **Stack Overflow isn't just for desktop browsers**. There are also other ways of reading Stack Overflow, which [I mentioned in my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283371/359284).

Comment: @martineau it'snotanextraspaceinthefirstplace

Comment: @KevinBrown This is my SE App on Android: http://i.imgur.com/nguT8ea.png and this is my browser on Android: http://i.imgur.com/sRkKz0D.png

Comment: @sehe That's after Lightness changed it to add spaces again, if you just took those.

Comment: @Kendra ok. Not confusing at all. Carry on

Comment: Switching between Desktop and Mobile views seems like a device-independent way to see the differences between the style sheets, based on my brief experimentation. If it's not currently the case, we can expect mobile users to become the majority soon.

Comment: @martineau You don't own your answers or their contents anymore once you post them on Stack Overflow, so don't worry about feeling vandalized.

Comment: @TylerH: I know I don't own them, but if nothing else my username is still associated with them.

Comment: What I find amusing is that martineau has started answering questions and placing spaces around the code.

Comment: @cybermonkey What's amusing about that? Seeing that the community disagrees with what you're doing and changing your behavior sounds like a great, mature response to me. Bravo to him if he has changed his mind based on this discussion.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Gotcha.

Comment: Hard to believe that there is a question, and answer, to "whether words should have spaces between them". Of course they should. Display methods are subjective, the data is not.

Comment: @martineau Using no spaces and expecting free space around keywords is leveraging undefined behaviour.  As programmers, surely we can agree that such a strategy is wrong.  It is not reasonable to insist you are correct when the code has clearly "broken the build".

Comment: @J...: I thought I was just being pragmatic and that doing so was benign, As I said in [another comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283362/spaces-around-code-keywords/283371#comment141922_283371) this wasn't something I was happy about having to do to get my posts to look the way I wanted.

Comment: @martineau If you are concerned about people associating your name with the use of spaces between words, you can always make such answers Community Wikis.

Comment: @martineau if you're worried about attribution you are more than welcome to request deletion of your account.

Comment: @hobbs: You really think that's something I don't know? Comments seem to be getting way off-topic. But in the same spirit, you're more than welcome to go ____.

Comment: @martineau: Maybe your profile misrepresents you, after all. Since your last comment is more like something I'd expect to see from a 13 year old on tumblr than a software professional on a technical Q&A.

Comment: @Lightness: Sorry. It's just my frustration with comments like the one I was responding to which seem to indicate (or feign) a complete misinterpretation of an earlier comment of mine about how, even though I don't own my answers once posted, they're still associated with me. It's not out of shame, guilt, or a desire to divorce myself from them. It's exactly the opposite, and due to that I still care about them and how the render. Makes me wonder whether there's just more folks here on meta that are denser than average, elitist, or just more inclined to make snide, passive-aggressive, remarks.

Comment: @martineau: You mean, such as that one?

Comment: Anyway, don't worry about it. :)

Comment: Lightness: Yes, that one, but other failures to understand, too, such as when you suggested that I write a custom stylesheet (though yours sounded sincere). I wasn't removing the spaces to make it look better just for me, which of course could be done that way. I was doing it so it would look better for the vast majority of folks out there _not_ doing something like that. Rational arguments and criticism are fine, like @J...'s point that I was relying on undefined behavior, which isn't the best strategy -- much different from saying it was ridiculous to have missed something SO obvious.

Comment: @martineau it's a reminder, and an encouragement.

Comment: @hobbs: Again, I'm perfectly well aware of the intent of your comments (which you're only further confirming). Since you're the one who doesn't seem to be grasping things, I'd like to urge you to do everyone the favor of taking your own advice...or at least to quit butting-in.

Comment: @martineau: Didn't we _just_ talk about this? Act your age i.e. grow up.

Answer (score 50):

I don't think there is any official guidance on this (though feel free to edit this if I am wrong) but in general, **most people use spaces to separate words in sentences**.

This includes words which are styled (like code), whichiswhy**youdont**`seethis`often ("which is why you don't see this often"). Yes, the in-line code formatting has some extra padding, but it appears that it is only meant to *improve* readability. The code is meant to stand out, which is why it is different, and fighting that only makes it more difficult to read. Just because it "looks fine" in one browser (or maybe two), that doesn't mean it's actually how it should look, or what the generally accepted way of doing it is.

This also has a serious impact on screen readers, as some will read it as a single word (because there are no spaces), which has the potential to either sound like garbage or be completely wrong. Yes, [people use screen readers on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5207/159034). No, *that shouldn't be the only reason* why you put spaces around code (and generally format things correctly), but it's one more reason to.

Comment: I don't want to undermine the screen reader argument, but they are pretty bad at reading code anyways ;p

Comment: @Killah The problem is that without the space the screen reader wont be able to read *the text* as well, since it gets mixed up with the code.

Comment: The screen reader angle is important; thanks for mentioning it. Even an *ideal* screen reader would arguably have trouble with text`without`spaces`but`with`markup`instead.

Comment: I agree that it just because it looked good in more that one browser (actually I tried it in a least 4, on two different OSs) doesn't mean that's how is should look. To be clear I wasn't doing this due to any malicious intent -- quite the contrary, in fact remembering and doing it is/was unnatural and a pain-in-the-butt which I do/did only out of irritating necessity (it seemed). Rendering-wise the only negative thing I ever noticed was that occasionally it would throw the automatic paragraph word-wrapping off (and require me to leave one or more spaces between words in).

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment of your post, but wouldn't a screen reader recognize `this<code>and</code>that` as three words and not one? I don't have any experience with screen readers, but that would make sense to me.

Comment: @JLRishe: As triplee said, the screen-reader issue sounds important -- and it's something I hadn't previously considered.

Comment: @JLRishe The screen readers I used usually read the text pretty much equivalent to `innerText` of elements, so they would read `thisandthat` if there are no spaces. More advanced ones were better at it, but hell, the `code` tag is only a markup, if you remove markup you should have the same text as with it. There should be spaces around the tags.